# Laravel name spacing issue

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I am using the IoC container in Laravel, I am trying to grab all the data from my database

```
<?php namespace API;

class ProductRepository implements ProductRepositoryInterface {

  public function getProducts()
  {
    return Product::all();
  }

}
```

When I run this I get this error

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'API\Product' not found
```

I am guessing it is trying to find the Product model in the API folder which I have namespaced. My question is how do I get my application to know that `Product:all()` should use the Product model. Is my name spacing correct? ProductRespository is sitting inside a folder called API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in a namespace, always prepend a `\` to any class in the root namespace:

```
public function getProducts()
{
     return \Product::all();
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can [`use`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) the class in your file:

```
<?php namespace API;

use Product;

class ProductRepository implements ProductRepositoryInterface {

    public function getProducts()
    {
        return Product::all();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah right ok, I see. Quick question is there a better way to do this? As when I try to use Response::json I get told the class is not found again, I don't really want to end up having to use multiple classes at the top of all my Repositories.

Comment: @joshuahornby10  - You shouldn't be returning responses from your repositories, but that's a discussion for another day. Suffice it to say there's no better way of handling this. For comparison, look at Laravel's [Model class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php) and its [Application class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php).

Comment: Can you point me towards some discussion on why you shouldn't return responses from repositories? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @joshuahornby10 - Your repos should be concerned about the http layer. That's the controller's job.

Comment: Yeh, fair enough makes sense. So in my case after I have all the products in `$this->product->getProducts()` in the controller I should do what? return the response there?

Comment: @joshuahornby10 - You can just `return $this->product->getProducts();` directly. It'll automatically be converted to JSON for you.